# PhantomJS fails to generate JPG from html source file

Tags: javascript, phantomjs

I am trying to generate JPG image from an html source, but script is producing 0KB JPG file, even
status=success

No error log for this html source.

Same script works fine for other html source dumps

HTML Source file :
https://goo.gl/Y2kcbM

Code is below :

```
var page = require('webpage').create(), fs = require('fs'),
address = "dump.html";

page.onError = function(msg, trace) {
var msgStack = ['ERROR: ' + msg];
if (trace && trace.length) {
    msgStack.push('TRACE:');
    trace.forEach(function(t) {
  msgStack.push(' -> ' + t.file + ': ' + t.line + (t.function ? ' (in function "' + t.function +'")' : ''));

});
}
console.error(msgStack.join('\n'));
};

console.log('isFile? ' + fs.isFile(address));
console.log('isReadable? ' + fs.isReadable(address));
page.open(address, function(status){
    console.log('status? ' + status);
    page.render('example.jpg');
    phantom.exit();
});
```

Comment: I ran it through an html validator. It looks like there are errors in your html.

Comment: But in browser it renders proper. Any best way to refine it?